# How to prove (forall n m : nat, (n <? m) = false -> m <= n) in Coq?

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

How to prove `forall n m : nat, (n <? m) = false -> m <= n` in Coq?

I got as far as turning the conclusion into `~ n < m` using by `apply Nat.nlt_ge`.

Doing `SearchAbout ltb` yields `ltb_lt: forall n m : nat, (n <? m) = true <-> n < m`, but I don't know how to apply this since it only deals with `(n <? m) = true`, not `(n <? m) = false`.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it: `intros. apply Nat.ntl_ge. contradict H. apply Nat.ltb_lt in H. rewrite H. discriminate. Qed.`

Comment: Where is `Nat.ntl_ge` defined?

Comment: Sorry typo, that should have been `Nat.nlt_ge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof that uses induction on n.

```coq
Require Import NPeano.

Theorem my_thm: forall n m, (n <? m) = false -> m <= n.
  induction n; destruct m; intros ; auto using (Le.le_n_S); discriminate.
Qed.
```